# C dereferencing pointer to incomplete type struct

Tags: c, struct

**In the tree.h header, I declared "struct privates" in order to hide the global variables. (relevant snippet)**

```
 struct privates;
  /*
   * a tree
     */

    typedef struct tree_node
    {
        struct tree *left; 
        struct tree *right; 
        struct tree_node *left; 
        struct tree_node *right; 
        float * info;  
        float distance_to_neighbor;
    } tree_node;


  typedef struct tree
  {
   /*in order to  keep track of the kd-tree root*/
   tree_node * _root; 
   /*pointer to internal variables struct*/
   struct privates* _privates;  

  } tree;

struct privates* init_heap_tree();

etc....
```

**In the implementation file kdtree.c , I defined the "struct privates": (relevant snippet)**

```
tree* my_tree=NULL; 

typedef struct  privates
{

/*variables*/
int current_number_of_tree_nodes; 
/*previous tree rebuild's node count*/ 
int previous_tree_size;
} privates; 


privates* init_heap_tree()
  {
      return (privates*) calloc(1, sizeof (privates));
  }


tree* tree_get_tree()
{
    my_tree = get_pre_allocated_tree();
    return my_tree;  
}

etc...
```

**Now in the memory management code, see relevant snippet of init_heap().**

I’m  attempting to set initialize values for struct members "tree_space->_privates->current_number_of_tree_nodes = 0;"

```
void
init_heap (int max_dimensions)
{
    tree_space = (tree *) calloc (tree_HEAP_SIZE, sizeof (tree));
    tree_space = get_pre_allocated_tree();
    tree_space->_privates = init_heap_tree();
    //THIS  IS WERE COMPILE  TIME ERROR OCCURS
    tree_space->_privates->current_number_of_tree_nodes = 0; 
    tree_space->_privates->previous_tree_size =0;  
    //allocate memory based on tree_HEAP_SIZE
    tree_space = (tree_node*) calloc (tree_HEAP_SIZE, sizeof (tree_node));
    tree_set_k_dimensions (max_dimensions);

etc...

}
```

"error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type "struct privates"

**I don't want any other design pattern for information hiding perse, How can I resolve this error with the struct member access?**

Thanks a million.

Comment: I think you may have two declarations of tree.

Comment: I don't see how you can have your cake and eat it too.  How is the compiler supposed to generate proper code in `init_heap` to modify the members of `_privates` if you won't tell it their types?

Comment: Is `init_heap()` defined in `kdtree.c` where the `struct privates` is defined, or in some other source file?

Comment: Some other header file. Thats just a snippet of were on trying access & set values.

Comment: Only the same .c file where the struct is defined can access private variables. That's kind of the whole point of using opaque types :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only functions in kdtree.c can access the members of `private`, so you need to do the initialization there.

```
privates* init_heap_tree()
{
    privates *rval = calloc(1, sizeof (privates));
    rval->current_number_of_tree_nodes = 0;
    rval->previous_tree_size = 0; 
    return rval;
}
```